# How to solve this arduino error-error: pins_arduino.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arduino

how do I solve  this error on my Arduino sketch,

In file included from sketch_feb14a.cpp:20:
G:\arduino-1.0-windows_2\arduino-1.0\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:212:26: error: pins_arduino.h: No such file or directory

Comment: I am using Arduino ADK  for Android

Comment: My guess is an include header directory is missing.

Comment: Can you guide me on how to go about solving it

Answer (score 7):

For the breadboard example I added this to the boards.txt that comes with the breadboard sample.

```
atmega328bb.build.variant=arduino:standard
```

Comment: THis was exactly the solution I needed. See the related issue: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/1370

Answer (score 3):

Double check what board you have configured in the IDE, Tools->Board
The pins file defines the pin configuration of your Arduino board.

If that's not it, then try a new install of the IDE.

Comment: I had configured the board correctly.But it worked once i re-installed the IDE.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should add:

```
sanguino.build.variant=standard
```

to `boards.txt` for the code to work in arduino uno.

Answer (score -1):

It is boot loader crashed issue.
Error come in below situations

1. IDE you downloaded is not proper
2. you have not configured comport or not selected Board you are working on
3. If above two steps properly done, that means you have uploaded program while loop/infinte loop which made boot loader to get hang.
   4.Include watchdog timer to get read of the problem again and again , after uploading boot loader
4. you will get avr Pocket programmer for burning bootloader